# how to compare two string values in apex

Tags: apex, string

I have to compare two string values in apex to determine whether they contain the same semicolon separated values or not (in any order). Could anyone please help me.

```
String str1 = 'Pay TV;AVOD;Basic TV';
String str2 = 'Basic TV;Pay TV;AVOD';
```

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Every question should demonstrate your work and research effort towards solving a question. SFSE's model is not to provide code for requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a string contains the same values as the other string but they aren't in the same order, you can load them to two sets and compare between them.

```
String str1 = 'Pay TV;AVOD;Basic TV'; 
String str2 = 'Basic TV;Pay TV;AVOD';
List<String> str1List = str1.split(';');
List<String> str2List = str2.split(';');
Set<String> str1Set = new Set<String>();
Set<String> str2Set = new Set<String>();
str1Set.addAll(str1List);
str2Set.addAll(str2List);

if(str1Set.equals(str2Set))
    system.debug('true'); // result: true
else
    system.debug('false');
```

Comment: str1set == str2set would work just as well.